# Догрузка JavaScrtipt и событие загрузки

Tags: javascript

По определенном событию мне необходимо подгрузить дополнительный  файл javascript и, после его загрузки и выполнения, выполнить некое действие. 
По задаче, вписывать какой либо код в подгружаемый скрипт не могу (может быть сторонний разработчик или с CDN, например)

Первую часть задачи делаю следующим образом

```
var mscript = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
var head = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ];
mscript.type = "text/javascript";
mscript.src = 'http://somesite.ru/script.js';
head.appendChild(mscript);
```

Есть ли какое либо событие, которое позволит выполнить действие после загрузки и выполнения скрипта. (В настоящий момент использую таймаут). Если необходимо для решения можно и jquery использовать.

Comment: `onload` у элемента script

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Слона то я и не заметил.... Почему комментарий, а не ответ? Я бы его отметил....

Comment: можешь сам написать, возможно даже дубликат есть уже

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена по комментарию Grundy. Для решения данной задачи надо определить onload для элемента скрипта

```
var mscript = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
var head = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ];
mscript.type = "text/javascript";
mscript.src = 'http://somesite.ru/script.js';
mscript.onload = function(){alert('Ok');};
head.appendChild(mscript);
```